# ReactiveMongoRepository insert return converter

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongodb, reactive-mongo-java

Insertion of an entity with an `Instant` value, using ReactiveMongoRepository:

```
MyEntity inserted = myReactiveMongoRepository.insert(entity).block();
System.out.println("inserted.getSent() = " + inserted.getSent());
// inserted.getSent() = 2022-09-17T00:20:58.399300383Z
```

Reloading the entity after insertion:

```
MyEntity loaded = myReactiveMongoRepository.findById(inserted.getId()).block();
System.out.println("loaded.getSent() = " + loaded.getSent());
// loaded.getSent() = 2022-09-17T00:20:58.399Z
```

The instant value has been trimmed to milliseconds precision in Mongo, which is fine.
Still, the insert above returns an object containing the original value.

**How to return the converted instant right away insertion?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain the calls.

```java
MyEntity insertedAndReloaded = myReactiveMongoRepository.insert(entity)
        .flatMap(inserted -> myReactiveMongoRepository.findById(inserted.getId())
        .block(); // don't block in production.
```

But there isn't any special support for reloading entities automatically in order to obtain generated data from the database.

Comment: This solution doubles the number of mongo DB turnarounds, doesn't it?